# Why is ldap_connect slow?

Tags: delphi, ldap

I am using the WinLDAP.DLL that comes with Windows to connect to different LDAP servers (1x OpenLDAP, 1x Active Directory). The programming Language is Delphi but it is probably not relevant here.

On several configurations the call of "ldap_connect" is really slow (6-7 seconds), when using the server name instead of the IP address. Pinging or making an nslookup of the same server is not slow. Why is it only slow with the ldap connection? Are there things that I could check to identify the problem?

**Edit**: WMware installed 2 virtual ethernet adapters on my computer. If I desactivate those adapters, ldap_connect gets 2-3 times quicker. It doesn't completely solve the problem, but it might help to find an explanation.

Comment: Can you please show us what is your "connection string"? I.e. do you make serverless binding (domain.lab) or you specify the name of the Domain Controller? Or it's better to show us at least ldap_bind/ldap_init/ldap_connect part of your program. Also is your dev machine joined the AD domain?

Comment: Also, are you using Netbios or DNS name when connecting to the LDAP server?

Comment: You can verify the delay by doing 2 wireshark/tcpdump traces, one on your computer and one on the LDAP server.

Comment: Name: some feedback would be nice :)

Comment: @iPath: My dev machine in on the AD domain. I have the problem on other systems too (not all) and not only with the AD Server, so I don't think this is specific to AD. I think it could come from the LDAP protocol (or implementation in WinLDAP).And I was using the Netbios name of the LDAP server.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: sorry, I wasn't able to answer earlier. I will try that with wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

That's almost certainly DNS misconfiguration. Check your nslookup and reverse lookup times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but nslookup requests are always quick. Until now I have only seen the problem with ldap connections.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are great that the LDAP server is doing a [reverse DNS lookup](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200105/msg00309.html).

Comment: Thanks, It might be an explanation why nslookup is fast and ldap slow. I will have a look at the suggestion in the link. But as I have the same problem with an OpenLDAP and an AD Server, chances are that the problem isn't on the server side but on the client side (but I don't know what it could be...)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know, why the connection is slow if I use the server name instead of the IP address. But to go around the problem, I decided to resolve the IP address myself instead of letting the WINLDAP.dll do it.

It can be simply achieved by using a function like this one:

```
function GetIPAddress(const HostName: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  HostEnt: PHostEnt;
  Host: AnsiString;
  SockAddr: TSockAddrIn;
begin
  Result := '';
  Host := HostName;
  if Host = '' then
  begin
    SetLength(Host, MAX_PATH);
    GetHostName(PAnsiChar(Host), MAX_PATH);
  end;
  HostEnt := GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(Host));
  if HostEnt <> nil then
  begin
    SockAddr.sin_addr.S_addr := Longint(PLongint(HostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
    Result := inet_ntoa(SockAddr.sin_addr);
  end;
end;
```